# Does "blob" really mean "Binary Large OBject" in git?

Tags: git, computer-science, terminology

I heard many people say git's `blob` is a abbreviation for "**B**inary **L**arge **OB**ject",
including [GitHub developer's guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/).

Is git's `blob` really means `binary large object` despite the following facts:

1. There are no git's official documents says that `blob` is an acronym.
2. `blob` is not always **large**
3. `blob object` is represented many times in git documents or codes. It doesn't mean *`binary large object object`*.

Comment: This is a [generic term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) for binary data, coming from databases. It's not git-specific. "blob object" is a [pleonasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), like "CD-disk".

Comment: Does it matter? If Git called them *zorble objects* or *klork objects*, they'd have the same function.

Comment: Actually, after reading that wiki article: originally, blob didn't mean anything, "binary large object" is just a backronym.

Comment: I was wondering whether `blob` is a just a word(could be any word) or it has a meaning.

Comment: It has a meaning: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blob

Comment: So `blob` means "a small drop or lump of something viscid or thick" like in dictionary?

Comment: from [git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefblobobjectablobobject):

_blob object_
_Untyped object, e.g. the contents of a file._

Comment: In git glossary, the hyperlink on `blob` or `blobs` leads to `blob object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git blob is the content of a Git object, which could by binary data.

See [git-scm.com docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

> #### 10.2 Git Internals - Git Objects
>
> ...
>
> ...  you aren’t storing the filename in your system — just the content. This object type is called a blob.

Noticeable [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/) does call it binary large object:

> #### Git Blobs
>
> A Git blob (binary large object) is the object type used to store the contents of each file in a repository. The file's SHA-1 hash is computed and stored in the blob object.